# Snowflake - How to get UploadDatetime in table via snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We are using snowpipe functionality to upload CSV data into our snowflake table.

We got the requirement to add new datetime field in table (DATAUPLOADTIME). Sometime it happens that our process took hours so client want to know Start time, Finish time and Data upload time in snowflake table.

We have done StartTime and Finish time but not Data upload time because we are not aware how to achieve this.

Please guide/advice.

Comment: If you're using Snowpipe to load a bunch of files it may be that there are many files and therefore many "Upload Times" , what do you mean by "Upload Time". Also, what are you using for StartTime and Finish Time?

Comment: We are scraping the data so we need 

StartTime (when scraping starts)
FinishTime (when scraping completes)
UploadTime (when data upload to snowFlake table)